# What's a good word for a "line of ink spread sideways"?

Tags: single-word-requests

I want to know correct word for a "line of ink spread sideways."

Comment: I'm not sure that there's actually a single word that encapsulates that phrase.

Comment: I think you're going to have to be more descriptive. You might be talking about *bleed* or *stroke* or *flare* ...

Comment: *smudge* also works.

Comment: schmersh ?? I'm not even sure how it's spelled.

Comment: Don't you just hate hit-and-run questions?

Comment: Are you referring to [Rorschach test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rorschach_test)?

Answer (score 4):

Do you mean an accidental *smear*? Or perhaps a calligraphic thick *stroke*?

Comment: +1 for smear. Similarly, _blot_, _smudge_, _daub_, _smirch_.

Answer (score 0):

*Downstroke* is a word that indicates a line going downward.  Is *sidestroke* a word for one going sideways?

It is not clear whether "spread sideways" is due to runny ink or to the direction of the stroke.

Comment: I interpreted as a line that's smeared perpendicularly or obliquely to the line.

Answer (score -1):

You could use the word "skein" figuratively.